# Bad computer battery? Dies after 45 minutes

Tags: laptop, battery

A friend gave me a Toshiba Satellite laptop. The battery would not charge and only worked when plugged in. I bought a replacement battery on Ebay. As I charged the new battery, I watched the meter. When it reached 58%, the meter read that it was plugged in but not charging. I unplugged adapter and ran laptop on the battery. It lasted about a half hour. I tried charging it for a few hours but, still no change. I contacted Ebay seller and his response was to try battery learning. I followed his instructions and now battery lasts 45 minutes and only charges to 87%. Here are the steps I have taken so far.             Replaced old battery with  new one the charging stopped at 58% with roughly half hour runtime.

Battery Learning steps

1. Charged battery fully (58%)
2. Removed adapter
3. Booted up, entered BIOS mode, left alone for 4 hours. Laptop died 30 minutes but left laptop and battery alone.
4. 4 hours later, confirmed battery had no power. Connected adapter and charged for 11 hours.
5. Booted up, charge was 87%, 45 minute life. Repeated Battery Learning, no change.     The battery charges approx. 1% per minute.

If anyone is familiar with this problem, please help. Thank you

Comment: This is typical behavior in fake "oem" batteries. There isn't much you can do about it, the actual battery, is the problem in this case.  Suggest you request a refund from the seller for a defective product.

Comment: I suspect that the battery is dead.  One point when buying L-ion batteries is to get fresh ones, from an outfit that sells a lot of them, as the battery has a relatively limited shelf life.  A battery that's been stored for 4-5 years is apt to be no good.

Comment: (But note that the "charging meter" on many laptops often indicates not charging when it actually is.  And note that some laptops have a utility that lets you limit the max charge, since always charging to 100% costs you battery life.  Look for something like "Toshiba Control Center" and see if there's an option to adjust charging.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got a battery that will not hold a charge because it is either used or defective.
There are utilities that will allow you to run some checks on the battery but judging by the things you have done already it sounds like it is a used battery that someone sold you as new.

You can google different battery testing software. Depending on what OS you are using you may want to see what is available.

Answer (score -1):

Most lithium ion batteries have an average lifespan of 300 charges or 3 years, which ever comes first.

Failing to exercise the battery periodically ( drain once a month or so)  can also shorten its life.

Unless it is still under warranty, you'll need to buy a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Install CPUID HW Monitor and you will see exactly the designed capacity and full charge capacity. If the full charge capacity differs more then 10% from the designed, then I would return it.

Comment: I have worked ten years as onsite IT support for a big corporation, so I think I know what I am talking about ;-) So if somebody gives minus to this give also a comment.